# API for backbone will be accessible by other website or devices

Tags: javascript, php, android, laravel, backbone.js

I am new in backbone, I am using php with Laravel framework as my server side language. I read to creating a single page application, I should create an API on my server side.

1. **Is this right (I should have an API for backbone single page application)?**
2. **Is this secure? (Other websites or devices like Android software can access it?)**

Comment: yes you right. for security, yes other websites and devices can acess it. just give username and password to give permission to acces your method in webservice

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira How can I send a user name and password by GET? it is not secure

Comment: Backbone doesn't enforce using GET, it can make other http calls as well

Comment: @RaviHamsa anyway, That is Javascript and the user can see the code