# better way to get data from a web page instead of working on DOM and HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am working with Backbone and before I worked with Jquery, before I used HTML Elements attributes as a variable to set data and when I need that information that was accessible in that HTML element.

**For example:** I had a image gallery and as you know each Image should have a title, Alt, src these are originally from HTML but I added a new attribute what called **mk-author**, ***mk*** was a prefix and when user clicked on that a image, The image maximized and the name of **author** will show beside of Image. sometimes I get the ID and do something maybe on server-side and of curse I validate it from server-side.

**Questions:**

1-Is this a secure, good way?

2-What is the betterway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, adding your own attributes gives you something that isn't quite HTML; it may work just fine but you're better off sticking to the standards (for future-proofing, portability, ...). Also, there's no need for them when the standard offers [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) that everything will understand, jQuery even has special support for them through the [`data` function.](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

For your image gallery example, a more idiomatic Backbone approach would have:

1. A model for each image in the gallery:

   ```
   var Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
       //...
   });
   ```

   Instances of this model would hold the image's URL, size, name, author, ...
2. A collection to hold the images:

   ```
   var Images = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       model: Image,
       //...
   });
   ```
3. A view for each image, this would provide the interaction and display for one `Image` model:

   ```
   var ImageView = Backbone.View.extend({
       events: {
           'click': 'show_details',
       },
       render: function() {
           // Build the HTML for `this.model` (an `Image`)
           // and add it to `this.$el`...
           return this;
       },
       show_details: function() {
           // The clicked image model will be `this.model`
           // so do whatever you need to.
       }
   });
   ```
4. A view to manage the entire collection, this mostly creates `ImageView`s:

   ```
   var ImagesView = Backbone.View.extend({
       render: function() {
           this.collection.each(function(image) {
               var v = new ImageView({ model: image });
               this.$el.append(v.render().el);
           }, this);
           return this;
       }
   });
   ```

Then you'd create your collection, populate it, and say something like:

```
var v = new ImagesView({ collection: images_collection });
$(container).append(v.render().el);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6Lcwfh98/

A little time with a Backbone tutorial and the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org) would be a good idea right about now.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, The backbone documentation is OK but that does not have demo and example and it is just defining functions. Can you please answer to [Thia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734575/api-for-backbone-will-be-accessible-by-other-website-or-devices) too?